# does the Scala compiler expose the functionality to turn a Scala name into the underlying JVM name?

Tags: scala

I am trying to get the underlying Java name from a Scala name.

For example:

```
scala> trait `Foo~`
defined trait Foo$tilde

scala> magicTranslatorMethod("Foo~")
res0: String = Foo$tilde
```

Is this functionality exposed in the Scala compiler/reflection/wherever public API somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scala> reflect.NameTransformer.encode("Foo~")
res0: String = Foo$tilde

scala> reflect.NameTransformer.decode("Foo$tilde")
res1: String = Foo~
```